# SPSS mixed format data management

Tags: spss

I have a data set in SPSS as follows:

```
ID  s2  s3   GP  Semester
1   1   1   3.00    1
1   1   1   4.00    2
1   1   1   2.00    3
2   1   0   2.00    1
2   1   0   3.00    2
2   1   0   4.00    3
3   1   0   5.00    1
3   1   0   6.00    2
3   1   0   7.00    3
4   0   1   2.00    1
4   0   1   3.00    2
4   0   1   6.00    3
```

To explain, I want the data in long format. Although `ID` and `Semester` indicate the data are in long format, but the variable `s2` and `s3` indicate presence of wide format as well. A special scholarship was given in semester 2 and 3. `s2` and `s3` indicates whether the subject (identified by `id`) got the scholarship or not in semester 2 and 3 respectively. As seen here, ID 1 got the scholarship in both semesters. ID 2 and ID 3 got the scholarship in semester 2. ID 4 got the scholarship in semester 3. But as the rest of the data are in long format, I want to create a variable that will have 1 in the semester at which the scholarship was received and 0 elsewhere. So, I want something like,

```
ID  s2  s3   GP  Semester Received
1   1   1   3.00    1        0
1   1   1   4.00    2        1
1   1   1   2.00    3        1
2   1   0   2.00    1        0
2   1   0   3.00    2        1
2   1   0   4.00    3        0
3   1   0   5.00    1        0
3   1   0   6.00    2        1
3   1   0   7.00    3        0
4   0   1   2.00    1        0
4   0   1   3.00    2        0
4   0   1   6.00    3        1
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
compute Received = (Semester eq 2 & s2 eq 1) | (Semester eq 3 & s3 eq 1).
exe.
```